# Screen resolution at VGA's 640x480 after upgrading from 21.04 to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 22.04, display-resolution, 21.10

On [my laptop](https://www.trustedreviews.com/reviews/xmg-u706) the screen resolution stays at VGA's 640x480 after upgrading from 21.04 to 22.04. I tried to install further updates in *Discover* (hoping that this would resolve the issue) but when I click *Install* there the pwd dialog appears for fractions of a second and then there's:

[image: Discover - Update_Issue]

I found [*Screen resolution stuck at 640x480 after upgrade*](https://askubuntu.com/a/650414/562424) but if I try to use *Xdiagnose* I get this in *Discover*:

[image: Discover - Xdiagnose]

and nothing happens no matter how often I click *Install*.

#### UPDATE

Any ideas how to restore my apps and settings I lost (as described in [my answer herein](https://askubuntu.com/a/1427948/562424))?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: @guiverc Well, "[_Issue upgrading 21.04 to 22.04 ... You need to upgrade to 21.10 first._](https://askubuntu.com/a/1410035/562424)" and this 21.10 was the version that was taken automatically when I performed `sudo do-release-upgrade -p`. I want to upgrade to 22.04 in the end.

Comment: The meta-file will show 21.10 is EOL & thus the upgrade path for [ubuntu-release-upgrader](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) won't upgrade to 21.10 anyway..  If it's a desktop, I'd recommend an *upgrade via re-install* ; I keep systems of all *supported* releases & when 21.04 reached EOL, I didn't need 21.10 as already had one so my 21.04 was used as a QA-test install of non-destructive install & became *kinetic* or 22.10 with my *manually installed* packages auto-reinstalled, music & user files untouched...  It's also faster than *release-upgrade* or *hacks*.

Comment: @guiverc Great that you had what you had and that worked what you did. I don't have that and this doesn't help me in any way. By _upgrade via re-install_ you mean purging this installation and perform a completely new one with the latest 22.04? Seriously?

Comment: @GeroldBroser no, if you run the installer without formatting your disk, it will install the new version while leaving all your files and applications alone. That is what is meant by "upgrade via re-install."

Comment: *Upgrade via re-install* is something I call it; older Ubuntu (desktop) used to call it *Repair installation* and it's *likely* returning as an option on the *canary* installed but doesn't work there *yet* last time I used it, but I've described it 30+ times on this site (often in comment) or in answers too.  Lubuntu call it *install using existing partition* (see [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) though intended for QA testers) but it's re-use of existing partitions **without** format! which triggers the repair/re-install.

Comment: The real intent was to *repair* an installation; ie. same release, but works fine in upgrading... It copes with Ubuntu repository software, isn't intended to *cope* with 3rd part software (*in QA only Ubuntu repository software is used*!) which makes it less useful for many end-users but they'll usually upgrade before EOL anyway. It's also not intended for server apps (which can store config/conf files in system directories that are erased prior to install; thus configs are lost!) but server apps aren't used in desktop installs.

Comment: "_This question is off-topic, as it is specific to an unsupported release of Ubuntu._"?!? 22.04 is a LTS: http://www.releases.ubuntu.com/ The first sentence of the Q reads: "_[...] after upgrading from 21.04 to 22.04._"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. GRUB's default selection is still the first one: *Ubuntu*. If I select *Ubuntu 21.10* a few items down the resolution matches the one of my screen.

(Really BIG) BUT all my system and app settings (e.g. Firefox settings and bookmarks) and all apps apart from the default are gone now there. That's really bad since I installed and configured a lot. Time for another AU question...or is there another way to bring all that back?

#### UPDATE

I just realized that the first GRUB selection *Ubuntu* is already 22.04, so apparently two upgrades have been performed in one. I performed (still in 640x480):

```
$ sudo apt update
...
$ sudo apt upgrade
...
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

(I was told  by `sudo apt upgrade` to do the last manually.)

Restarted afterwards and the proper resolution and all settings/apps are back now!

There are, however, "*No available connections*" in the bottom panel network icon drop-up. Though there are 3 Wi-Fi in *System Settings* > *Network* > *Connections*. WT...H?!?

I connected an Ethernet cable, restarted Kubuntu, the network adapter's lights are on on the router but there's nothing about it in ... *Network* > *Connections*. WT...even more...H?!?

(I'm sorry having to say that this is one of the worst journeys I had when upgrading an OS since 40 years in IT. And it doesn't end here.)

Activated mobile hotspot on my cell phone, to no avail.

Connected my cell phone via USB, activated USB-tethering, to no avail.

There's one notification:

> Network Management
>
> Failed to get secrets for [...]_2.4G
> No agents were available for this request.

[...]_2.4G is one of my WLANs.

#### UPDATE 2

Cont'd at [*"No available connections" after upgrading from 21.04 to 22.04*](https://askubuntu.com/q/1427974/562424).

#### UPDATE 3

I ended up with abandoning Ubuntu and installing [openSUSE Tumbleweed](https://www.opensuse.org/). This means a few days of installing/configuring now but I don't have mercy with OSs that do not work as they did before after an upgrade. Fortunately with Linux there's always an alternative.